# code works in js fiddle but not in dreamweaver or on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jsfiddle, spritely

http://jsfiddle.net/reveries/9Dt7n/
http://www.reveriesrefined.com/test/

When you hove over the door, it's supposed to animate... and in jsfiddle  it works brilliantly, but once I put this code on my website, it stops working. You will still see the image, but when you hover over it, there's no animation. I'm wondering if maybe js fiddle has some hidden code that i'm not including??

jQuery (w/srpitely)

```
var iFrames = 23,
iFps = 24,
bRewind = false,
iStartFrame = -1,
bAnimating = false,
stopAndRewind = function(oAnim) {
    iStartFrame = ~iStartFrame ? -1 : iFrames - 2;
    bRewind = !bRewind;
    bAnimating = false;
    oAnim.spStop();
};
$("#door").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
var iCurFrame = iStartFrame;
if ($._spritely.instances && $._spritely.instances[$(this).prop("id")])
{
    if (bAnimating)
    {
        iCurFrame = $(this).spGet("current_frame");
        stopAndRewind($(this));
    }
    $(this).destroy();
}
bAnimating = true;
$(this).sprite({
    fps: iFps,
    no_of_frames: iFrames,
    start_at_frame: iCurFrame,
    rewind: bRewind,
    on_frame: (function() {
        var o = {},
            i = 1;
        if (!bRewind)
        {
            i = iFrames - 2;
        }
        o[i] = stopAndRewind;
        return o;
    })()
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Completely Changed Answer**:

On your website, you have invalid characters in the `/test/javascript/open_close.js` file. So nothing in that file will work, because the parser chokes on them.

The end of the file is:

```
});â€‹

});
```

Note the invalid characters.

If you copied-and-pasted from jsFiddle, that's probably where they came from. jsFiddle's editor fields have these weird characters in them, I don't know why. I've noticed it several times in the past.

---

**Original answer before actually looking at website (having missed the link)**:

You have jsFiddle set to include your code in an `onload` handler, so it happens very late in the page load cycle, once all the DOM elements are there (and images have downloaded, etc.). (This is jsFiddle's default, I couldn't tell you why, you're not the first to fall afoul of it.) If your own page has the script just inline, and in particular if the `script` tag is above the elements its working with, that's the problem.

Comment: so should I include:  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
    code...etc...

Comment: @user1868086: A lot of people do. I personally believe the only valid use case for `ready` is libraries. If you control where the `script` element goes, just put it at the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Then it will have access to all of the elements defined above it (which is to say, all of them). That's what the [YUI folks recommend](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), and the developers behind [Google Closure](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I think you must be looking at the wrong thing. All the relevant `<script>` elements *are* just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @ruakh: Ah, I didn't even really see the link to his site, so I was working on theory. Thanks.

Comment: yep, ruakh is right, all the <script> elements are right before the </body> tag. Should I include the script for the animation in my html doc? I even tried putting only the code from the js fiddle into dreamweaver (with dom ready/onLoad, tried both) so that there wouldn't be any other code interfering with it. Even that didn't work. I tried linking all images and javascript/jquery to my website, and also tried downloading all the files and running it locally. Nothing worked.

Comment: @user1868086: Look and the updated answer (or at ruakh's). Your `open_close.js` file is messed up.

Comment: I just checked, and the open_close.js file is fine, there aren't any illegal characters in it.

Comment: @user1868086: But there are. At the very end. Depending on your text-editor, they might look invisible; you might try going to the very end of the file and hitting "backspace" and "delete" a few times, then retyping the last few JavaScript characters.

Comment: @user1868086: No, it isn't. It has the invalid characters I mention above (they may be invisible in your editor), and Chrome's console clearly shows errors caused by them, as does Firebug's.

Comment: haha it was invisible in my scrpt editor from my website, but you were right!!! thanks it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is *the* problem, but Firefox's Error Console reports that you have some garbage characters at the end of `open_close.js`.